# Best practices for microservices internationalization and localization

Tags: localization, internationalization, microservices, translation, language-translation

Like the subject says, I am searching for best practices for how to handle i18n and l10n in a microservice architecture. There doesn't seem to be a lot out there on this topic, but surely others

So, in a relatively complex system consisting of a set of microservices, possibly developed in a mix of languages and with the code hosted in a separate git repo per service, built with a Jenkins pipeline, how do you go about localizing this system? I have done some research, but haven't been able to find anything in terms of best practices for this kind of setting. Specifically, I am interested in how to set up and manage continuous localization in such a setting. 
Thanks!
Cheers,

Martin

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Handle localization in microservices architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/391498)

Answer (score -1):

You don't localize the data into the microservices, as they are part of the backend. Into a backend, you only handle keywords. Then in the GUI, you have a i18n system that replaces each keyword by the appropriate sentences. It's not specific to microservices, you should do the same with a monolith.

For example, the backend returns a person like this : `{"name":"Paul","job":"cook"}` ("job" is a closed list of jobs like "cook", "salesman", "teacher", ...), and the GUI have the following code :

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
i18next.init({
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        "job": "Job",
        "cook": "Cook",
        "salesman": "Salesman",
        "teacher": "Teacher"
      }
    },
    fr: {
      translation: {
        "job": "Métier",
        "cook": "Cuisinier",
        "salesman": "Vendeur",
        "teacher": "Enseignant"
      }
    },
    es: {
      translation: {
        "job", "Trabajo",
        "cook": "Cocinero",
        "salesman": "Vendedor",
        "teacher": "Profesor"
      }
    }
  }
});

...

// display the translation according to the current language
jobLabel.innerHTML = i18next.t("job");
jobField.innerHTML = i18next.t(person.job);
```

If your GUI has an incomplete translation, the keyworkd will be displayed, which is usually an acceptable downgraded solution.